# How can I control my media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I'm trying to make my website responsive, but whenever I resize my browser the content start changing and getting messed up. I tried to fix it but I need to fix every possible dimension because for example I set up media query for 432px and when I resize it to 440px i have an extra unwanted white space somewhere. I'm using vh and vw  for divs and containers and % for positioning. Anyways do I have to set mediaqueries to each new dimension if not please tell me if there is a trick to it to avoid this extra hard work.

Comment: you need to post your code if you want to get any useful answers

Answer (score 0):

You can create just 4 different media queries like some of the Twitter Bootstrap framework

```
//For extra small devices, phones
@media (max-width: 480px)

//For small devices, tablets
@media (max-width: 768px)

//For medium devices, desktops
@media (max-width: 992px)

//For large devices, wide screens
@media (max-width: 1200px)
```